# How can I validate params that don't corrospond to a db column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, param

I have a model `User` with a string attribute `name`. On my form to create a new `User`, it's easy to validate the `name` attribute:

**models/user.rb**

```
validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 13}
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :words)
end
```

However, I want to validate a param that *isn't* an attribute or db column. On my form I have a textbox that submits `params["words"]` as a string. I know the param is being submitted because I can interact with it using `binding.pry`. But if I try to validate it the same way as Name, nothing happens. The form submits with or without `words`. How can I validate a param that isn't an attribute?

**my form:**

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => users_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <input id="words" name="words">
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, I updated my answer below to address your second question, regarding how to get your form to post the parameter nested under User.  If I have addressed all of your questions successfully please mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to perform model validations that include *:words* then you need to add :words as a virtual attribute in your User.rb file so the model has access to it.  You can do that simply by adding this line to your User.rb file:

```
attr_accessor :words
```

Then your model can now perform validations on it such as:

```
validates_presence_of :words
```

You also need to ensure that the :words param belongs to :user and is being sent as `params["user"]["words"]`

---

**Edit:**

To get your form to post the :words parameter nested under :user change your form input to:

```
<input id="words" name="user[words]">
```

*or* since the user model now has the virtual attribute :words you can set your form the rails way.

```
<%= f.text_field :words %>
```

---

APIDock reference on attr_accessors:
http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor

Virtual Attribute Reference:
http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/ruby_tutorial/Ruby_Classes_Objects_and_Variables_Virtual_Attributes.html

Answer (score 1):

The form should submit `params['user']['words']` rather than `params['words']`, and your User model should have `attr_accessor :words`.

Comment: How can I make it submit `params['user']['words']`? I added my view code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your value in `params[:user][:words]` instead of `params[:words]` and add `attr_accessor :words` in your model.

Comment: How can I make it submit `params['user']['words']`? I added my view code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it adding the `words` attribute to `User` class.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :words

  validates :words, presence: true, length: {maximum: 13}

  def initialize(arguments = {}, options = {})
    self.words = arguments.delete :words
    super
  end
end
```

But, override `ActiveRecord` initialize method isn't recommended. It seems that this validation should occurs only in this action.

The correct approach should be use a Form Object. You can learn more here: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/